# Conflicting data length for column (3) Unicode

Tags: sql-server, ssis, visual-studio-2017, ssis-2012, teradata-sql-assistant

I'm trying to transfer data from `Teradata` to `SQL Server`, but I have a problem. When it tries to take the data from the source (TD) it gives me this error:
 `Conflicting data length for column (3) - "Description". Source column's data length is (40) Target column's data length is (60).` But my column in the table is 20 Unicode. I understood that the problem would be from UNICODE (I can't change the table / column data type in TD). I tried the following methods to "convert".

- the first method was to take the column with the function `Translate` in expression builder/`sql` command: Translate (Description using unicode_to_latin with error) in the expression builder. Like this it works, data is inserted, but in SQL Server the inserted data appear OK (some of the data) and others are not OK (those that have special characters). How could I add special characters (for Russia or other country that has special characters)?:

[image]

- Another method I tried was to specify in the expression builder the Description column to be (DT_WSTR, 40):

> "SELECT "+(DT_WSTR,40)"StoreDimLevelDescription"+", from bd"

- The expression works but unfortunately when I run it doesn't work and it gives me the above error.
- I also tried to change from TD SOURCE, from "Show Advanced Editor ..", -> INPUT & OUTPUT properties -> TD Source Output -> External Column -> Description -> DataType seted to Unicode String [DT_WSRT]. Same for the Output Columns. I clicked OK, but from what I noticed my data is not saved.
- For TD Source I'm using MS Connector for Teradata by Attunity (provider).
- And for SQL Server Destination I'm using ADO.NET.

What do you think..?

Comment: First things first, what is the data type of the column in SQL Server? It should be `NVARCHAR` to support storing non-Latin characters.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I tried with VARCHAR(40) and NVARCHAR(40), it still shows me '?'

Comment: Sure, but it's important to establish the target column can at least hold the data, otherwise no amount of configuring inside the package will help -- so make sure the target is `NVARCHAR` and that SSIS shows it as `DT_WSTR`. The next thing that is peculiar is the complaint that there is a column of length 60 which doesn't match. This appears to match neither your source column nor your target column, so maybe this refers only to the SSIS type definitions?

Comment: @JeroenMostert I tried with NVARCHAR but it doesn't change me from DT_STR to DT_WSTR. I thik that error comes from the source, ie from TD, not from SQL SV. I think it's because in INPUT and OUTPUT I have DT_STR and in TD my column is VARCHAR (20) UNICODE (i tryed to change in INPUT/OUTPUT data type but when i press ok it doesn't save).  I guess this doesn't refers tot the SSIS definitions.

Comment: This is an Attunity issue. You seem to always get DT_STR when source is a SELECT. You can get DT_WSTR when source is a table and you use UTF8 session, but because the Teradata API gives max length in bytes and Attunity incorrectly assumes that length is characters, the SQL Server target has to be defined as 3X.

Comment: @Fred, So, I have to define the length from SQL Server with 3X ? (20x3)

Comment: Anyway I have the same error.

Comment: Yes, target NVARCHAR(60) if source is VARCHAR(20) UNICODE. And even then I don't think it works if the source is a SELECT statement, it has to be based directly on a table (or view) on the Teradata side.

Comment: @Fred Doesn't work..

Comment: I've tried to set DefaultCodePage = 65001 (UTF8) or unicode.. nothing happens

Comment: I don't understand why I can't change the INPUT/OUTPUT into DT_WSTR

Comment: Then you may have to use something other than Attunity / TPTAPI for this extract, e.g. generic ADO.NET connection with Teradata's .NET Provider, or even generic ODBC connection with Teradata's ODBC driver.